# replacing mirror.js shaderLib['mirror'] with built in material

Tags: three.js

I am trying to reuse the existing basic, lambert, and phong material so I can have bumps, normal maps, ..etc on my mirror reflections. I am using the latest revision of three.js which is 87.

I have tried using the onBeforeCompile function to append and replace part of the MeshBasicMaterial vertex and fragment code but my mirror is not showing.
Can someone please help. Thank you.

Here is what I have did in the mirror.js

/* commented out the existing code that use the shaderLib mirror shader

```
    var mirrorShader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "mirror" ];
    var mirrorUniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( mirrorShader.uniforms );
    //console.log('opacity:', this.mirror_opacity)
    mirrorUniforms['opacity'].value = this.mirror_opacity;

    this.material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

        fragmentShader: mirrorShader.fragmentShader,
        vertexShader: mirrorShader.vertexShader,
        uniforms: mirrorUniforms,
        transparent: true

    } );

    this.material.uniforms.mirrorSampler.value = this.renderTarget.texture;
    this.material.uniforms.mirrorColor.value = mirrorColor;
    this.material.uniforms.textureMatrix.value = this.textureMatrix;
```

*/

/* Here is the material I am replacing with */

```
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var texture = textureLoader.load("images/test.jpg");
    this.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture});
    var mirror_texture = this.renderTarget.texture;

    this.material.onBeforeCompile = function ( shader ) {

        let mirrormap_pars_vertex = [
            'uniform mat4 textureMatrix;',
            'varying vec2 texCoord;',
            'varying vec4 mirrorCoord;\n',
        ] .join('\n');          

        shader.vertexShader = mirrormap_pars_vertex + shader.vertexShader;
        shader.vertextShader = shader.vertexShader.replace(
                    '#include <begin_vertex>',
                    [
                        'vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );',
                        'vec4 worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );',
                        'mirrorCoord = textureMatrix * worldPosition;',
                        'texCoord = uv;',
                        'gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;\n',
                    ].join( '\n' )
        );


        let mirrormap_pars_fragment = [
            'uniform vec3 mirrorColor;',
            'uniform sampler2D mirrorSampler;',
            'uniform sampler2D maskSampler;',
            'varying vec4 mirrorCoord;',
            'varying vec2 texCoord;\n',
        ].join('\n');

        shader.fragmentShader = mirrormap_pars_fragment + shader.fragmentShader;

        shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(
                    '#include <map_fragment>',
                    [   
                        '#ifdef USE_MAP\n',
                        'vec4 mask = texture2D(maskSampler, texCoord);',
                        'vec4 color = texture2DProj(mirrorSampler, mirrorCoord);',
                        //'vec4 texelColor = texture2D( map, vUv );',
                        //'color = vec4(blendOverlay(mirrorColor.r, color.r), blendOverlay(mirrorColor.g, color.g), blendOverlay(mirrorColor.b, color.b), opacity);',
                        //'color.a *= texture2D(maskSampler, texCoord).g;'
                        'diffuseColor *= color;',
                        '#endif\n',
                    ].join( '\n' )
        );      

        shader.uniforms.mirrorSampler = {type : "t", value : mirror_texture};       
        shader.uniforms.textureMatrix = { type: "m4", value: new THREE.Matrix4() };
        shader.uniforms.maskSampler = {type: "t", value: null}
        shader.uniforms.mirrorColor = { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color(0x7F7F7F) };

        console.log("shader", shader )
```

Comment: As an alternative approach, see [this three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_mirror_nodes.html).

Comment: It would be easier if I could just use the existing materials as I need lightmaps, normals, bumps..etc. I do not know why my mirror does not display when trying to replace the map_fragment.

Comment: If I change 'vec4 color = texture2DProj(mirrorSampler, mirrorCoord);', to 'vec4 color = texture2D(mirrorSampler, vUv);' then my mirror reflection is displayed but the coordinates are not correct.